# Java - Load a correct XML from System.in

Tags: java, xml, input, executable-jar, jdom

I am trying to load an XML document from `System.in` in order to be able to pipe my program. But the XML doesn't seem to load correctly since I get a `NullPointerExeption` where my program is looking for root element.
I am trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488107/5669411).

Here is my code to load from `System.in` (never prints out "ok") :

```
org.jdom2.Document jdomDoc
public LoadFile(String fileLocation) {
    if (fileLocation.compareTo("System.in") == 0) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        log.info(sc.toString()); // debug purpose
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            log.info("ok"); // debug purpose
            jdomDoc.addContent(new Element(sc.nextLine()+ "\n"));
        }
     }
```

And I give fileLocation "`System.in`" if no -i (input) parameter has been found. I run it from cmd with :
`myXml.xml|java -jar myProgramm.jar`

Comment: What are you expecting `fileLocation.compareTo("System.in")` to do?

Comment: How to pipe to Java program - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724646/how-to-pipe-input-to-java-program-with-bash

Comment: @cricket_007 This line is simply used to check if  `String fileLocation` equals `"System.in"`, else I read from the given file

Comment: I understand, but are you explicitly passing the string `System.in` into your method? If so, that's not really clear. It's also not clear how you are calling this method or why you are using a pipe operation to read the file

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks, I obviously didn't do enought research but I still get the same error...

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I am explicitly giving the string `System.in` to my method, this method is called in my main : `LoadFile file = new LoadFile(xmlIn);` and I want to pipe it so that it can be automated and doesn't need to have files saved on the drive as input

Comment: The files are already saved on disk, though. A BufferedReader only reads as much as you put into its buffer, so I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @cricket_007 If so I don't understand either. Anyway I was explicitly asked that the programm can read piped data

Comment: Alright, well, seeing as this isn't a [mcve], not too sure what else to tell you. You've got a NullPointerException. Your `jdomDoc` variable is never initialized in your question code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, dumb error, simple typo in my command : forgot
**type** `myXml.xml|java -jar myProgramm.jar`